# Change default Cognito Hosted UI in Amplify to use an website in mobile (desktop mode)

Tags: reactjs, redirect, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

#### Describe problem

I have a responsive website (react) that uses Cognito as Amplify Auth. The problem is that when the user made Sign In to my customized login page, he/she can't change from mobile mode to desktop mode without being redirected to Cognito Hosted UI.

#### Expected behavior

The user doesn't need to confirm login every time he/she changes the view from mobile mode to desktop mode or vice versa. Even if it is extremely necessary to ensure login, at least the user should be redirected to my own customized page.

#### For more detailed informations (devtool imgs and screenshots)

See more in oficial Amplify-js Github forum [#issue11293](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/11293)

#### aws-exports.js

```
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "XXXXX",
    "aws_cognito_region": "XXXXX",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "XXXXX",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "XXXXX",
    "oauth": {
        "domain": "XXXXX",
        "scope": [
            "XXXXX"
        ],
        "redirectSignIn": "XXXXXXX",
        "redirectSignOut": "XXXXXX",
        "responseType": "code"
    },
    "federationTarget": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    "aws_cognito_username_attributes": [
        "XXXXXX"
    ],
    "aws_cognito_social_providers": [
        "XXXXXX"
    ],
    "aws_cognito_signup_attributes": [
        "XXXXXX"
    ],
    "aws_cognito_mfa_configuration": "OFF",
    "aws_cognito_mfa_types": [],
    "aws_cognito_password_protection_settings": {
        "passwordPolicyMinLength": 8,
        "passwordPolicyCharacters": [
            "XXXXX"
        ]
    },
    "aws_cognito_verification_mechanisms": [
        "XXXXX"
    ],
    "aws_content_delivery_bucket": "XXXXX",
    "aws_content_delivery_bucket_region": "XXXXX",
    "aws_content_delivery_url": "XXXXX"
};


export default awsmobile;
```

#### Additional information

Please, note that this is a problem similar to [#issue2115](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2115) and [#issue5027](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/5027) and both issues used `urlopener` using dependencies in React Native to resolve. Maybe the solution to my bug is something similar but considering React (not React Native).